# Python / BeautifulSoup - Scraping XML data from Clinicaltrials.gov API - parse data within XML parent/child tags

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to working with XML and BeautifulSoup and I am trying to get a dataset of clinical trials using Clinicaltrials.gov's new API that converts a list of trials into an XML dataset.  I tried using `find_all()` like I typically do with HTML, but I'm not having the same luck. I've tried a few other approaches, like converting to a string and splitting (very messy) but I don't want to clutter my code with failed attempts.

**Bottom line**: I want to extract all NCTIds (I know I can just convert the whole thing into a string and use regex, but I want to learn how to actually parse XML correctly) and official titles for each clinical trial listed in the XML file.  Any help is appreciated!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import lxml.html

url = 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/full_studies?expr=diabetes+telehealth+peer+support&+AREA%5BStartDate%5D+EXPAND%5BTerm%5D+RANGE%5B01%2F01%2F2020%2C+09%2F01%2F2020%5D&min_rnk=1&max_rnk=10&fmt=xml'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
m1_nctid = soup.find_all('Field Name="NCTId"') #This comes back with 0 results
m1_officialtitle = soup.find_all('Field Name="OfficialTitle"') #This comes back with 0 results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can filter on attributes like following:

```
m1_nctid = soup.findAll("field", {"name" : "NCTId"})
m1_officialtitle = soup.findAll("field", {"name" : "OfficialTitle"})
```

and then iterate each result to get text, for ex:

```
official_titles = [result.text for result in m1_officialtitle]
```

for more info, you can check the documentation [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the `field` tag in lowercase, and pass `name` as an attribute to `attrs`. This works with just `BeautifulSoup` there's  no need to use `etree`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/full_studies?expr=diabetes+telehealth+peer+support&+AREA%5BStartDate%5D+EXPAND%5BTerm%5D+RANGE%5B01%2F01%2F2020%2C+09%2F01%2F2020%5D&min_rnk=1&max_rnk=10&fmt=xml"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

m1_nctid = soup.find_all("field", attrs={"name": "NCTId"})
m1_officialtitle = soup.find_all("field", attrs={"name": "OfficialTitle"})
```