# Scraping XML data from ClinicalTrials API V2

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to reproduce the results of these questions:
[Scraping xml data from clinicaltrials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011389/python-beautifulsoup-scraping-xml-data-from-clinicaltrials-gov-api-parse-d) and [extracting xml data from clinicaltrials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70029265/python-beautifulsoup-extracting-xml-data-from-clinicaltrials-gov-only-able) using the new [ClinicalTrials V2 API](https://clinicaltrials.gov/data-about-studies/api-migration). According to it, `/api/query/full_studies` should be replaced with `/api/v2/studies`

However, when I try it, I received 0 results

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

def download(keyword):
    #base_url = "https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/full_studies"
    base_url = "https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/v2/studies"
    params = {
        "expr": palabra_clave,
        "min_rnk": 1,
        "max_rnk": 40,
        "fmt": "json"
    }
    response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        return None

result = download("diabetes")
result
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, running your code I receive data.

Comment: Yes, because that's old API. If you change base_url = "https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/v2/studies" it does not work

Comment: Please ensure the code you post is the code that is NOT working.  Also, your code ignores any HTTP status besides 200.  What is the status code when it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://clinicaltrials.gov/data-about-studies/learn-about-api) you need to change name of parameters too:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests


def download(keyword):
    base_url = "https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/v2/studies"
    params = {"query.term": keyword, "format": "json"}
    response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        return None


result = download("diabetes")
print(result)
```

Prints:

```json
{'studies': [{'protocolSection': {'identificationModule': {'nctId': 'NCT04617405', 'orgStudyIdInfo': {'id': 'PADME1'}, 'organization': {'fullName': 'University of Aarhus', 'class': 'OTHER'}, 'briefTitle': 'Hormonal and Inflammatory Changes During Pregnancy in Women With Glucose Metabolic Disorders.', 'officialTitle': 'Hormonal and Inflammatory Changes During Pregnancy in Women With Glucose Metabolic Disorders.', 'acronym': 'HI-MET'}, 'statusModule': {'statusVerifiedDate': '2022-11', 'overallStatus': 'RECRUITING', 'expandedAccessInfo': {'hasExpandedAccess': False}, 'startDateStruct': {'date': '2021-01-11', 'type': 'ACTUAL'}, 'primaryCompletionDateStruct': {'date': '2023-12', 'type': 'ESTIMATED'}, 'completionDateStruct': {'date': '2023-12', 'type': 'ESTIMATED'},

...
```